# Why is 'speech-dispatcher' listed so many times in sound settings and what is it?

Tags: gnome, sound, gnome-control-center

Yesterday the list looked like this:

[image]

Today the list looks like this:

[image]

So what is this `speech-dispatcher` that I have never seen before? And why so many of them?

**Information Update:**

I went into Universal Access, and it was off, I tried turning it on and then off again in there, but it makes no difference, the entries in the sound application list are still there.

When running the command `ps xa | grep -P 'speech-dispatcher.*\.conf'` the output is:

```
17906 tty2     Sl+    0:09 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_espeak /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/espeak.conf
17911 tty2     Sl+    0:01 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_cicero /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/cicero.conf
17915 tty2     Sl+    0:01 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_generic /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/generic.conf
17918 tty2     Sl+    0:01 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_dummy /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/dummy.conf
24407 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto -P speech-dispatcher.*\.conf
```

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.16
```

Comment: Did you try some text-to-speech software or a screen reader?

Comment: @muru: Yes, I used the built-in Screen Reader ORCA for GNOME earlier today.

Comment: @ByteCommander: Oh yes sorry, I meant `speech-dispatcher`.

Comment: I got 4 x "speech-dispatcher "and 6 x "AudioICP Server" on Linux Mint 18.3. Screen reader has never been used and is off.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have enabled the ScreenReader in GNOME, that's all. To disable the Screen Reader start <kbd>Universal Access</kbd> and click <kbd>Screen Reader</kbd>.

---

You can see four entries in <kbd>Sound</kbd>, because there are four processes

```
% ps xa | grep -P 'speech-dispatcher.*\.conf'
14520 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_generic /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/generic.conf
14523 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_cicero /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/cicero.conf
14527 tty2     Sl+    0:03 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_espeak /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/espeak.conf
14532 tty2     Sl+    0:00 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_dummy /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/dummy.conf
```

Sometimes the processes, however, seem to be not properly terminated after the Screen Reader was terminated. Therefore:

```
killall speech-dispatcher
```

As said [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/speech-dispatcher/+bug/1496542), it is a known upstream bug which is currently being worked on.

Comment: I went into Universal Access, and it was off, I tried turning it on and then off again in there, but it makes no difference, the entries in the sound application list are still there.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda As you're a 6.8k user, you might not know yet that it's no good practice to drop command outputs or to generally provide additional information in comments. Please [edit] your question and include it there, using the code format button! **;-D**

Comment: @ByteCommander: Oh... Sorry! :D I've updated my question now with that **formatted** information.

Comment: @ByteCommander He, the edit link edits my answer ;)

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot that `[edit]` obviously links to the current post's edit page, not the current question's one. Probably because I only or at least mainly use it with questions... I apologize! ;)

Comment: Every day i have to kill it all once! And the other day the same. It needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 8):

In my setup, most of the GNOME stuff is not used and in the `gnome-control-center` there were a lot of `speech-dispatcher` processes as well. I hadn't the Screen Reader enabled.

But still, the processes were there. I had to disable the service using systemd tools:

```sh
sudo systemctl disable speech-dispatcher  # disables systemd service
```

And kill the remaining processes after that like in the accepted solution:

```
killall speech-dispatcher
```